# mingw mysql c++ connector crashes on driver connect

Tags: c++, mysql, mingw, windows-7-x64, connector

C++ MySQL is crashing on driver connect with minGW on windows-7.

I am trying to connect MySQL with c++ connector. Connector been downloaded from MySQL Site. Followed instruction on MySQL site: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/index.html

I have installed C++ connector on Windows7 64-bit host. MySQL is installed on the same host. I am using Mingw to compile the code with Boost 1.56 with below compile command.

g++ sample_MySqlCpp.cpp -std=c++11 -pthread -I./MySQLConnector_C_drive_1.1.4/include -I./MySQLConnector_C_drive_1.1.4/include/cppconn -I./boost_1_56_0_only_MySql_connector -L./. -lstdc++ -lmysqlcppconn

I have copied the said dlls and libs from Connector folder and when I run the code I see it's crashing at driver.connect: Output (below) states that driver is not null. I tried all other methods and issues mentioned in other threads like checking the debug vs retail builds, 32-bit dll vs 64-bit builds, etc but of no help.

Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message'...
Driver: 0x522160

```
/* Standard C++ includes */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

/*
  Include directly the different
  headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
  (and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/
#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;
//using namespace sql;
//using namespace sql::mysql;

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message'..." << std::endl;

    try {
        sql::Driver *driver;
        //sql::Driver *driver;
        sql::Connection *con;
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *res;

        /* Create a connection */
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        if(driver == nullptr) {
            std::cout << "Failed to get driver" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        std::cout << "Driver: " << (void*) driver << std::endl;

        con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
        /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
        con->setSchema("test");

        stmt = con->createStatement();
        res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message"); // replace with your statement
        while (res->next()) {
        std::cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
        /* Access column data by alias or column name */
        std::cout << res->getString("_message") << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
        /* Access column fata by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
        cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
        }
        delete res;
        `enter code here`delete stmt;
        delete con;

    }
    catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
        std::cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        std::cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        std::cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        std::cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << std::endl;
    }

  return 1;
}
```